# Fancybox changing next & previous image source

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I am just wondering is there a way of changing the next and previous image sources before they are being clicked? I just need Fancybox to automatically resize the images since when I do it manually after the user clicked the next or the previous button (I need to do it manually), the size won't change and sometimes it gets stretched. Is there a fancybox attribute which would allow me to set the source of the next and previous images so that it will work fine on slideshow and slider?

Example of my code for setting the next image source -

```
jQuery(".fancybox-arrow--right").on('click', function () {
        var next = parseInt(index) + 1 + count;
        if(next >= newborns.length)
        {
            console.log("Last Image");
            jQuery(this).prop('disabled', true);

        }
        else{
        console.log(next + ' Next');
        var newImg = new Image();
        newImg.src = newborns[next];
        var height = newImg.height;
        var width = newImg.width;
                if (height > width){
                //  jQuery(".fancybox-image").css("height","569px");
                //  jQuery(".fancybox-image").css("width","379px"); 
                /*  setTimeout(function(){
                    jQuery(".fancybox-image-wrap").css("transform","translate(274px, 44px) scale(1, 1)");   
                    },50);  */
                } else {
                //      jQuery(".fancybox-image").css("height","569px");
                //      jQuery(".fancybox-image").css("width","853px"); 
        /*      setTimeout(function(){                      
                        jQuery(".fancybox-image-wrap").css("transform","translate(136px, 44px) scale(1, 1)");
                    },50);  */                      
                }
        jQuery(".fancybox-image").attr("src", newborns[next]);          
        count++;
        }   
    });
```

The issue with that is that it's dependant on a user clicking the arrow and the image doesnt resize properly, on a slideshow it doesnt work at all. Basically I have an array of image sources and I track the clicks on which image the user clicks on and take the index, with this index I can tell which image will be next or previous but that is only known after the user has clicked on the image. Do you guys have any suggestions as to how should I approach it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to solve something from the wrong end. Do not over-complicate things.

1) Either create your own click handler that 1) Creates gallery items; 2) Then starts fancybox manually;

2) Or use `beforeLoad` callback to manipulate with the image source. You could also use `afterLoad` callback to tweak image dimensions (https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/gdVyxg?editors=1010)